# Junk characters in csv file during export

Tags: c#, csv, file-io

I am trying to export dynamic string content on csv file. But when any currency symbol comes like `$`,`€`, csv file shows junk characters right after the currency symbol.
 eg:

```
 string dynString = "test user,$15,452.00,USA";
```

the value in the above variable is dynamically generated
 when the csv is opened it looks like

```
 "test user,$?15,452.00,USA"
```

I have tried `UTF8`, `UTF16`, `UTF32`, `UniCode`, `Windows-1252` but nothing worked.

Below is my code:

```
string dynString = "test user,$15,452.00,USA";

databaseField = System.Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(dynString ));
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Reading a line from a CSV file into a variable? Writing a variable as a line of a CSV file?

Comment: Please post sample code that shows the problem (check http://www.sscce.org for guidance). You've shown only half of the code which does not have problem, you need to show the second half (reading your base64 string) which should contain issues with incorrect encoding detection.

Comment: I am writting the dynamic content of a variable into csv file. 
UTF8 shows junk characters once i convert dynString variable value to bytes array. However i tried other encoding like Windows-1252,UTF16. They show correct value (after converting back to string from byte array for diagnose purpose) but start junk characters again once writting to csv file operation is done.

Comment: Below is the code
Entity activityMimeAttachment = new Entity("activitymimeattachment");
activityMimeAttachment.Attributes["objectid"] = new EntityReference("email", "7110FA46-1A5F-E311-A8A3-534E57000000");
activityMimeAttachment.Attributes["body"] = System.Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(dynString ));
CRMServiceObject.Save(activityMimeAttachment);

Comment: Again - there is nothing wrong with code that you've posted - it does exactly what is written and reverse operation will produce correct string (from base64 and UTF8 to string). It looks like you have no idea what encoding you are expected to use, but SO will not be able to help you to get this bit of information about your local CRM system (or whatever you use to "export to file").